# Need help with steam!

Tags: steam

I recently downloaded Dota 2 from steam and earlier I was playing it then I turned my computer off for awhile because it was hot and when I went back to play it I opened steam and it wasn't in my downloads and when I click the desktop icon it created for Dota 2 it brings up the install thing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it will work if you open it **through steam** now, because suddenly turning off the computer can make the program file corrupted by deleting essential bits & pieces that were running before you suddenly turned the computer. If you try opening through steam **AND** tells you to install, do it, because the corrupting of the file must have been so bad that it became fully unreadable by the computer in a way.

***TIP:*** you turned the computer in such a way in first place because it too hot right? Try to minimize the amount of applications that are running in the background to keep the computer cool as well as put it on top of a very heat absorbing material so as to make sure it's not the computer that gets heated up.

Answer (score 0):

Open .steam folder in your home directory > steam > SteamApps > common and check if dota2 folder is there and check it's size.

If it's there go one level higher and check if any of the appmanifest file contains name dota. If not, you have to obtain the appmanifest file for dota and put it there. Either from other Linux machine or from Internet.

Then open Steam, right click on Dota 2 > Properties > Local Files > Verify cache integrity. It will download any files you are missing.

If there are not data for dota, then something deleted it and you would have to download it anew.

Comment: Yea the dota 2 folder is there but the appmanifest file is in the  SteamApps folder. So i have to put the appmanifest file in the dota 2 folder? http://imgur.com/jzTi3dW

Comment: No, this is how it should be. So just try to Verify cache integrity as described.

Comment: Where is Dota 2? The desktop icon?

Comment: No, in steam Library tab

Comment: Oh yea in the steam library. but i cant do that because the game doesnt show there

Comment: Is there another way to verify cache integrity? http://imgur.com/r1kwcHW

Comment: Did you try to restart Steam? If the game is not at all showing in your library, the appmanifest file is probably damaged, please post the content here.